# Storing object id's in vector<pair<id, object>> vs separate map<id, ind> and vector<object> vs map<id, object>?

Tags: c++

Suppose we have an `std::vector` of objects that have their ids, but object id is not stored in its object. Let just for example that object be an `std::string`.

```
typedef int id_t;
typedef std::string obj_t;
```

So we have an option to store these objects in `std::pair`s along their ids:

```
std::vector<std::pair<id_t, obj_t>> storage;
for (size_t i=0; i < outer_storage.size; ++i){
    storage.emplace_back(outer_storage.get_id(i), outer_storage.get_data(i));
}
```

or to store their ids in a separate `map` `id<->index`:

```
std::vector<obj_t> storage;
std::map<id_t, int> ids;
for (size_t i=0; i < outer_storage.size; ++i){
    storage.emplace_back(outer_storage.get_data(i));
    ids.emplace(outer_storage.get_id(i), i);
}
```

or to store objects directly in `map`:

```
std::map<id_t, obj_t> storage;
for (size_t i=0; i < outer_storage.size; ++i){
    storage.emplace(outer_storage.get_id(i), outer_storage.get_data(i));
}
```

Which method is better in terms of execution time, RAM usage, etc...?

Comment: The choice of a data structure rather depends on what operations you need to perform on that data structure. Which you haven't described.

Answer (score 0):

For memory usage, version 1 is best. Has almost no overhead except keeping track of the vector data pointer, size and capacity. In most cases only 32 bytes. A map needs to store a tree structure used to arrange and find the elements.

Performance? Depends on what you mean.

Time to populate the data structure?
Version 1. Just remember to reserve its size before doing push_back/emplace_back.

Time to look up an entry?
Depends on the number of elements. For a low amount, linear search through a vector is going to be faster. For more elements, the map will be faster. Where the break-off point is is hard to say, may vary on lots of factors.
If the vector is sorted you could do binary search, which may move that point upwards.

Iterating over the elements?
Version 1 will be faster, since it stores all elements continuously in memory, which improves cache usage.

Inserting new/deleting elements? Depends on size and where the insertion/delete is done.